# Cisco stacking - priority and number information

Tags: cisco, switching, cisco-catalyst

In case of switches stacking, where are stored the information about the switch number and the switch priority ?
After a reset, these information were conserved.

Comment: I am unclear about what your exact question is, but there is plentiful information on Cisco switch stacks out there and it should be quite simple to find. [This](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750/software/release/12-2_52_se/configuration/guide/3750scg/swstack.html), for example, covers it pretty well.

Comment: Thanks, the question was, in which memory the information about number and priority are stored. I thought it was in the NVRAM inside the configuration, but after a switch reset (=NVRAM deletion), the information about the switch number and priority remain. So in which memory these information are stored.

Comment: How was it "reset"? There's a ROMMON environment variable that's outside any normal configuration in NVRAM.

Comment: With the mode button (2960X).